# How to search with full name using like in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, search, sql-like

Currently there is first_name, middle_name and last_name in separate fields I can search using above names but now I want to search with full name:

My Code:

```
    $attorneyName=$address=$firmName="";
    if ($request->has('attorneyName')) {
        $attorneyName = $request->attorneyName;
    }
    if ($request->has('address')) {
        $address = $request->address;
    }

    try {
        $attorneyResultQuery = Attorney::query();
        if (!empty($attorneyName)) {
            $attorneyResultQuery->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $attorneyName . '%');
            $attorneyResultQuery->orWhere('middle_name', 'like', '%' . $attorneyName . '%');
            $attorneyResultQuery->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $attorneyName . '%');
            $attorneyResultQuery->orWhereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ',middle_name, ' ',last_name) like '%?%'",$attorneyName); // searching with full name
        }
        if (!empty($address)) {
            $attorneyResultQuery->where('street_address', 'like', '%' . $address . '%');
        }
        $searchData=$attorneyResultQuery->get();

        return response(['status' => true, 'message' => 'Searched Data', 'data' => $searchData], 200);
    }catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return response(['status' => false, 'message' => 'Validation Errors', 'errors' => $ex->getMessage()], 500);
    }
```

as you can see I am doing like this

```
 $attorneyResultQuery->orWhere("concat(first_name, ' ',middle_name, ' ',last_name) like '%?%'",$attorneyName);
```

This is my body request

```
  {
"attorneyName": "Bilal nadeem hy",
  }
```

I am searching with first_name (Bilal) middle_name (nadeem) and last_name (hy) but it's showing my all other records as well if I search with full name. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
$attorneyResultQuery
    ->orWhereRaw(
        "concat(first_name, ' ', 'middle_name', ' ', last_name) like '%" . $attorneyName . "%' "
    );
```

Comment: This **has** very significant performance downsides on a large table.

Comment: this worked, but I don't know why it doesn't work with japanese

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is any of the answers looks confusing, try this simple method. Using Laravel's `whereRaw` method, I run the query. You could also use `orWhereRaw` method depending on your use case.

```
MODEL_NAME::query()
            ->whereRaw(
                "TRIM(CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', COALESCE(other_name, ''))) like '%{$term}%'"
            )
```

Where MODEL_NAME is the name of your model on which you would want to construct the query and $term search term :).

I used the **COALESCE** function in MYSQL because the other_name field in my database can be NULL. COALESCE is used here to return the *other_name* if it is NOT NULL and and empty string `''` if it is NULL.

The query would work for names with or without spaces in it.